# Anti-debugging/Anti-disassembly resources

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering

I want to write an Anti-debugging/Anti-disassembly program that will make the binary it is protecting secure against tampering while on disk and in memory (like cryptanium). 
What are the best resources for this (books)? (Mac OS X/iOs initially, it may be ported to Windows, android latter).

Comment: What language? This is impossible for some, e.g. C# and JavaScript.

Comment: C/ Objective-C ... On Windows Visual C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protecting an executable binary against reverse engineering without hardware means is generally recognized to be impossible, regardless of the source language. The best that you can hope for is to use an obfuscator to make the disassembled code difficult to manually reverse engineer. This will stop low-budget hackers but will have no effect on high-budget hackers (corporate level) who have de-obfuscation software that can reduce the obfuscated code to minimal execution paths. At the very best it will delay reverse-engineering.

However, obfucators can be an effective means of protecting low-value code. If the code that you are writing isn't worth the effort to de-obfuscate, then there is a low chance that anyone will bother to try.

Writing a good obfuscator requires expertise that you need to gather from many different sources. There is an [annual contest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Obfuscated_C_Code_Contest) for C obfuscators. You might start there. Note that most of the examples are **not** general obfuscators, but are simply examples of obfuscated source. See also [this post to Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/129296/the-case-for-code-obfuscation).

There are a small number of commercial products, such as [Rummage](http://www.aldaray.com/Rummage) for .NET. IMHO the small number of commercial offerings is testiment to the inefectiveness of the technique except for low-value code.

Comment: I'm much more interested in preventing an attacker with remote debugging capabilities (kernel rootkit on a machine running the protected software) will not be able to interfere with it or read user data from it while in memory..

Comment: @user1028028: The problem is that if you are root you can do *anything*. You should consider a hardware solution such as running the software on a device, and interfacing it to the host through PCIe, USB or similar.

Comment: Yes but: I'm counting that the anti debugging will deter a REMOTE attacker form gaining certain info from the app in a covert way. So if he tries the app will crash or become non-responsive and alert the user of a break-in. It's more of a secondary data protection mechanism than DRM. Even as a DRM I want to make an attacker spend quite a few hours trying stuff before any success. I do realize that any anti-debugging can be beat with sufficient time.

Comment: @user1028028: If your software or data is valuable, e.g. credit card or blackmail info, then there is enough incentive for an effective attack. There is not much to do against a rootkit. It can copy any page in memory or from the page cache and examine it separately.

Comment: The thing is it will not be able to determine the page very easily, and will make the app highly unresponsive.